# Calling an overridden method from the base class in Ada

Tags: oop, polymorphism, ada

I am wondering how to call an overridden method from the parent class in ADA. Let consider the following example. A `Parent` class has some methods which are overridden by a `Child` class. There is a method in the `Parent` class (i.e., `Prints`) which calls some of its overridden methods. But the overridden methods are not called! Here is the example:

**--- parent ---**

```
package Parents is 
    type Parent is tagged null record;

    procedure Prints(Self: in out Parent); 

    -- these will be overridden  
    procedure Print1(Self: in out Parent) is null;
    procedure Print2(Self: in out Parent) is null;        
end Parents;
...
package body Parents is        
    procedure Prints(Self: in out Parent) is
    begin
        Put_Line("Parents.Prints: calling prints...");
        Self.Print1;
        Self.Print2;
    end;        
end Parents;
```

**--- child ---**

```
With Parents;
package Childs is 
    type Child is new Parents.Parent with null record; 

    overriding procedure Print1(Self: in out Child);
    overriding procedure Print2(Self: in out Child);    
end Childs;
...
package body Childs is         
    procedure Print1(Self: in out Child) is
    begin
        Put_Line("Child.Print1 is printing...");
    end;

    procedure Print2(Self: in out Child) is
    begin
        Put_Line("Child.Print2 is printing...");
    end;        
end Childs;
```

**--- main ---**

```
procedure Main is  
    anyprint : access Parents.Parent'Class;
begin           
    anyprint := new Childs.Child;
    anyprint.Prints;
end Main;
```

**problem**

What I am expecting to see is the dispatched calls to both `Print1` and `Print2` from `Child`.  But the overridden methods are not called! Having C++ background, this type of polymorphic calls make sense for me but I cannot figure out how Ada treats them?

Is the invocation `Self.Print1;` from `Prints` wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ada, dispatching only happens when the object is of a class-wide type. The relevant manual section is [ARM 3.9.2](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-9-2.html).

In `Parents.Prints`, the controlling operand `Self` is of type `Parent`, and is “statically tagged”, so there is no dispatching.

One approach is to use “redispatching”, which looks like this:

```
procedure Prints(Self: in out Parent) is
begin
   Put_Line("Parents.Prints: calling prints...");
   Parent'Class (Self).Print1;
   Parent'Class (Self).Print2;
end;
```

in which the view conversion `Parent'Class (Self)` means that the object on which `.Print1` is invoked is "dynamically tagged" and the call dispatches.

As you have it, `Prints` is able to be overridden in derived types. This isn’t always (or even usually?) what you want. If not, it’d be appropriate to change its parameter to be class-wide:

```
procedure Prints(Self: in out Parent'Class);
```

(and in the body, of course!) and then everything works as you’d expected.

[A side note: I’ve now learned that the *object.operation* notation works with class-wide objects!]

Answer (score 3):

One way to think about this is to think about it at a low level, i.e. what code is generated by the compiler.

When the `Prints` procedure is compiled, and the statement `Self.Print1` is seen, the code generated by the compiler is a *non-dispatching* call.  That means that the compiler figures out the address (or external symbol) for the `Print1` method, and generates a call to it.  It is not an indirect call, but rather a call to a fixed address, which will be the `Print1` that appears in `Parents`.  The reason it's non-dispatching is that the type of `Self` isn't a classwide type (it's just `Parent`, not `Parent'Class`).

When you declare the `Child` type, it will inherit the `Prints` procedure.  That is, there is an implicitly declared procedure that looks like this:

```
procedure Prints (Self : in out Child);  -- inherited procedure
```

But the compiler does not generate new code for this implicit procedure, if you don't override it.  So when `Prints` is called, even if it's called with a `Child` parameter, the code will be the same as if it were a `Parent` parameter.  And the code, as explained in the previous paragraph, makes a fixed call, not a dispatching (indirect) call, to `Print1` and `Print2`, which will still be the ones declared in `Parent`, because the code was generated when `Parent` was compiled.

Back to the call in `Prints`:

```
Self.Print1;
```

If the type of Self were `Parent'Class`, or if you used a view conversion to convert it to `Parent'Class`, as in Simon's answer (`Parent'Class(Self)`), then the call would be *dispatching*, meaning it's basically an indirect call.  The code would figure out the address of the correct procedure at run time, and make an indirect call to it.

The difference between Ada and C++ is that the Ada compiler uses the *type* of the object it's operating on to determine whether to make a dispatching (indirect) or non-dispatching (call).  If the type is classwide, it's dispatching, otherwise it's fixed.  C++, however, uses a property of a method, not a property of a type, to decide which kind of call to make; if the method is marked `virtual`, then calls to it are dispatching, and if not, they're fixed.  (At least I think that's the case; I'm not really a C++ expert.)

By the way, the same applies even if you don't use Object.Operation notation.  If, instead of `Self.Print1`, you said

```
Print1 (Self);
```

that would be a non-dispatching call; but

```
Print1 (Parent'Class (Self));
```

is a dispatching call.